# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Услышала в передаче такую фразу: "...не откроет нам своих секретов". Разве так можно говорить? Разве не "...свои секреты"?
А то сразу вспоминается стишок из "Понедельник начинается в субботу": "Перетряси своих подвалов и шкафов перетряси..."))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При переходных глаголах с отрицательной частицей НЕ могут употребляться существительные в винительном и родительном падежах, которые часто выступают как синонимы. Существительные во множественном числе чаще всего стоят в родительном падеже. Кроме того, родительный падеж предпочтительнее у отвлеченных и абстрактных существительных. Поэтому фраза "...не откроет нам своих *секретов*" абсолютно правильна.